# c# capture Ctrl+PageUp keystroke

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, keyboard, keystroke

I am having trouble capturing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> keystroke in a ListView control in WinForms application.

I am using this code to capture keystrokes -

```
private void ListViewEx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
...
if(e.Control){
if((e.KeyCode ^ Keys.Left) == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Left"); //shows messagebox
else if((e.KeyCode ^ Keys.PageUp) == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("PageUp"); //does not
...
}
```

Do I need to dive into WndProc to process this key? Thanks.

---

Edit: I've found out that this works, the problem was in enclosing TabControl handling these keys before ListControl got to them.

Comment: Actually, on further investigation, your code works out when I test it. Is there something happening in the code that you have left out before the if block that may interfere in some way?

Comment: no, it does not work - I have a derived ListView control, and every key combination works except for Ctrl+PageUp or Ctrl+PageDown. These two keep focusing some other control in the form.

Comment: Ok, I've just made a test application where this all works, and when I rent further to reproduce the problem and added TabControl, I found out that it was TabControl who was eatin' my keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for WndProc:

```
if ((e.Modifiers & ModifierKeys) == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.PageUp)
{
    // ctrl + page up was pressed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The e.KeyData argument includes the modifier keys.  Make it look like this:

```
  if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.PageDown)) {
    // Do your stuff
    Console.WriteLine("Ctrl+PgDn");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

check for

```
Keys.Control | Keys.PageUp
```

Comment: This will not work since the `KeyDown` event contains information about what key that triggered the event, not what keys are currently pressed. So you will get two separate `KeyDown` events: one for the Control key and one for the PageUp key.